# How import and use method from outer js-file into AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I should like to use functional from this file https://ahunter.ru/js/min/ahunter_suggest.js

The documentation says that
1. import files

```
<head>
...
  <script src="path_to_scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="path_to_scripts/ahunter_suggest.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

2. Add id for input field

```
<div>
  <input id="js-AddressField" placeholder="Введите адрес">  
</div>
```

3. Add script

```
<script>
  var options = { id : 'js-AddressField' };
  AhunterSuggest.Address.Solid( options );
</script>
```

I added file to my project directory and added link into index.html, but i can't call 
`AhunterSuggest.Address.Solid( options );` in one of my controller.

How will do it right?

Answer (score 0):

In your AngularJS controller, u have a method for initialising the controller right? If so, you have to call 3rd party library initialiser (3rd code in your message)

Make sure to call this, after dom is ready and angularJS controller initiated.

Your angular controller before (atm)

```
init() {
  this.xxx()
}
```

Angular Controller after: (should be sth like this)

```
init() {
  this.xxx()
  this.initialiseAHunterSuggest()
}
initialiseAHunterSuggest() {
  var options = { id : 'js-AddressField' }
  AhunterSuggest.Address.Solid( options )
}
```